# Unable to connect Android phone to my project with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I created my project in react native by CLI:

```
_npm install -g create-react-native-app
_create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
_cd AwesomeProject
_npm start
```

Then I installed `expo` in my Android phone, and scanned a QR code on my computer screen.

However, my phone can't connect to project, and I don't know why. It just loads and fails. This is error message:

> Could not load exp:// 192.168.56.1:19000. Network response timed out.

This is view error:

> "Uncaught Error: java,not.SocketTimeoutException: faild to connect to/192.168.56.1 (port 19000) after 10000 ms.

I'm trying to fix it, but still can't get it working. My phone and my laptop are on the same network. What can I do now?

Comment: Did you use EXPO SDK on your laptop?

Comment: May be not. I just follow the instructions in "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html". So what does it mean ?

Comment: With Expo SDK, expo will generate tunnel link to your local ip, or you can publish your react native app to their server so you can always look your app when you turn off dev mode. I have some problem when using local ip.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem but solved by running `expo start --tunnel`

Comment: Tunnel is very very slow, instead connect phone with usb and do the same.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: would like to know how this works. is it just using ngrok as a tunnel from computer to phone?

Comment: why does not work without --tunnel?

Answer (score 9):

Select LOCAL instead of LAN.

[image: screenshot]

I kicked myself when I fixed this.

Comment: Where is this setting? I could not found in expo go app

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, turns out my **firewall was blocking my connection** to the development server port (for me it was 19000). Solved it by **disabling firewall.**

Comment: Thanks! I was able to open port 19000, that also seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

Choose **Tunnel** Instead of **LAN** or **Local** in connection tab. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

Keep a look on this issue for the answer:
https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/60

Comment: oh my ghost, my issue was solved. I desibled all virtual network and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that your device and computer are one same LAN/Wifi. It will work.
Also use LAN option.

Comment: yes, thank for your opinion, In my case, I have installed virtual box and this is why it confuses network to connect.

Comment: This solved it for me. My computer and device were on different networks. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'm on windows 10.

My network was set to **public**, but it needed to be **private** - so that it could safely expose devices like printers and in this case the Expo connection.

I went in my Wifi setting and clicked on Private:
[image]

Comment: How does this solve the problem?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson as stated in my answer, it allows the network to be exposed and visible to the Expo internal requirements. I don't know how Expo does that but without this configuration in the Windows Wifi settings, it was impossible for Expo to connect with my Android device. This solution is probably part of other problems but in my case it solved it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using windows 10 do the following. It worked for me.

1. Check if your phone and PC are sharing the same router/hotspot/wifi connection. better still you can connect your PC to your phone hotspot.
2. Configure the network you are using as private. You can do so using [this link](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-your-networks-location-private-or-public-windows-10/).
3. Off your windows defender and any other antivirus. The windows and other antivirus defender acts as a firewall and prevents expo client from working. It will work I assure you.

Comment: I only needed to go up until step 2 and it worked! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

for local testing e.g comnputer , simulator

`expo start`

for Real mobile device

`expo start --tunnel`

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem on iOS - the project showed up in the Expo app but didn't want to connect.

Here's what I did:

1. Connect your PC to your device through USB cable
2. Download the newest xde from: https://github.com/expo/xde/releases
3. Install XDE, create a new project from the gui (do NOT use your old project from create-react-app, as it may also show up in XDE) and click the newly created (in XDE) project under "My Projects".

Now your project should show up in the Expo app on your phone. If it doesn't try sending yourself the link to your app over email (to your own inbox, and open the link on your phone), mine looks like this: `exp://5c-gp9.[accountname].my-new-project.exp.direct:80`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when my phone was connected via wifi and my destop was connected via LAN. I changed the connection mode in the browser window to tunnel, reloaded the expo app and was able to connect to my application. This was on my iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue on Win 10 with android and solved by the adding a firewall rule for my device (device IP as remote). I was using ESET NOD antivirus and it was block the device from accessing node.exe

Answer (score 1):

check open port using

```
ufw status verbose
```

And if you don't see the port You are working on
for example 19000 => expo
try this

```
ufw allow 19000
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, the solution is easy just make a **Firewall rule** that allows connection from your mobile device to your PC. open **port number 19000** and in the IP put your phone IP address then allow the connection **TCP/UDP** in both directions, and everything will be OK.
Usually, you can edit the Firewall rules through your antivirus installed on your PC.

**Careful don't disable your firewall, it will hurt you a lot.**

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the sdk version of the project is not compatible with the expo go  ,so go to app.json of your project and edit to the latest version of sdk

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove .expo directory and and then try again.